# Incorrect Context error for bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view() only if looking through active camera

Tags: scripting, 3d-view, camera

I am writing an operator to create a new camera to capture one frame renders, thumbnails etc.

It works if you are in a 3D View and not looking through an existing camera. However if you are looking through a camera it fails here:
'RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view.poll() failed, context is incorrect'

I'm confused as I believe the context should be correct? Any help much appreciated.

````
import bpy


class OBJECT_OT_make_test_camera(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Make a test camera"""
    bl_idname = "object.make_test_camera"
    bl_label = "Make Test Camera"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D'

    def execute(self, context):
        cameraName = "SimpleRenderCam"
        cam = bpy.data.cameras.new(cameraName)
        cam.lens = 90
        cameraObject = bpy.data.objects.new(cameraName, cam)
        bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(cameraObject)
        bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.data.objects[cameraObject.name]
        area = bpy.context.area.type
        print(str(area))
        bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view()
        return{'FINISHED'}


class VIEW_3D_PT_test_camera(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Test Camera"
    bl_label = "Create camera to test area"
    # bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        area = bpy.context.area.type

        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.label(text="View type is:")
        row.label(text=str(area))

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('object.make_test_camera')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW_3D_PT_test_camera)
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_make_test_camera)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW_3D_PT_test_camera)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_make_test_camera)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The operator does not poll in 'CAMERA' view.**

Conveniently when using an operator that relies on another, can use the others `poll` method as our own.

The button will now be disabled when the operator does not poll, and avoid the error above.  *The operator is also disabled in the `Align View` menu*

[image]
*Button disabled in Camera Perspective View*

This is perhaps a good thing since you get in this state by assigning camera to view, and will have to re-orientate to make the op viable again.

Otherwise set the 3d viewport to another mode or tweak view matrix slightly to move from camera view.

```
import bpy


class OBJECT_OT_make_test_camera(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Make a test camera"""
    bl_idname = "object.make_test_camera"
    bl_label = "Make Test Camera"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view.poll()

    def execute(self, context):
        cameraName = "SimpleRenderCam"
        cam = bpy.data.cameras.new(cameraName)
        cam.lens = 90
        cameraObject = bpy.data.objects.new(cameraName, cam)
        context.scene.collection.objects.link(cameraObject)
        context.scene.camera = cameraObject
        print(context.area.type)
        bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view()
        return{'FINISHED'}


class VIEW_3D_PT_test_camera(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Test Camera"
    bl_label = "Create camera to test area"
    # bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.label(text="View type is:")
        row.label(text=f"{context.area.type}")

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('object.make_test_camera')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW_3D_PT_test_camera)
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_make_test_camera)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW_3D_PT_test_camera)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_make_test_camera)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

To make the operator return in a state to run again, set the view to perspective before return in operator execute.

```
        context.space_data.region_3d.view_perspective = 'PERSP'
        return{'FINISHED'}
```

To have your operator poll and run in camera view add an or clause .

```
return bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view.poll() or context.space_data.region_3d.view_perspective == 'CAMERA'
```

Since the view operator wont poll outside 3d view, this being false saves us the need to worry that the space is anything but a 3d space.

Will also have to set the view before calling operator to avoid the operator poll.

Comment: Great explanation. 
One thing I'm not seeing at the moment when testing polling the camera_to_view operator is the button being disabled when looking through a camera. I can see that the operator in the view menu is disabled though. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Not sure. Added an image showing button in Camera view disabled via camera to view poll method.

Comment: Ok try now. Lost a poll() pasting it appears.  Handy little op btw, found I've used it heaps already.

Comment: Ah yeah, working now.
Very handy indeed, I hadn't realised you could use poll to that extent. Many thanks :)